# how to update Bidirectional @OneToMany relationship

Tags: jpa, sql-update, one-to-many, bidirectional

I have Employee and Functions, Bank classes 
Employee and Function have `@OneToMany` relationship and
Employee and Bank have also `@OneToMany` relationship.
if the user edits the form and change the function and/or bank
I want to update the relationship. but when I change the relationship
I get Duplicate entry  exception due to the uniqueness of a column because
the Employee object persisted as a new entity

I tried to remove the employee from the function and set the employee's function to null and get a new function and add the employee to it
and set the new function but it doesn't work. any idea, please

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends GeneratedIdEntity<Long> {       
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   private Functions function;

   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   private Bank bank;

   @OneToMany(
           mappedBy = "employee",
           fetch = LAZY,
           cascade = ALL,
           orphanRemoval = true
   )
   private List<RubricValue> rubricsValues = new ArrayList<>();

   @OneToMany(
           mappedBy = "employee",
           fetch = LAZY,
           cascade = ALL,
           orphanRemoval = true
   )
   List<EmployeeStatus> employeesStatus=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Functions extends GeneratedIdEntity<Long>{
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "function",
            fetch = LAZY,
            cascade = ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Employee> employees=new ArrayList<>();    

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee ){
        employees.add(employee);
    }
    public void removeEmployee(Employee employee){
        employees.remove(employee);
    }    
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Bank extends GeneratedIdEntity<Long> {
   @OneToMany(
           mappedBy = "bamk",
           fetch = LAZY,
           cascade = ALL,
           orphanRemoval = true
   )
   private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

   public void addEmployee(Employee employee ){
       employees.add(employee);
   }
   public void removeEmployee(Employee employee){
       employees.remove(employee);
   }
}
```

```
@Stateless
public class EmployeeService extends BaseEntityService<Long, Employee> {
    @Inject
    FunctionService functionService;

    @Inject
    BankService bankService;

    public void update(Employee employee, String newFunctionName, String newBankName) {
        if (!employee.getBank().getName().equals(newBankName)) {
            employee.getBank().removeEmployee(employee);
            employee.setBank(null);
            Bank newBank = bankService.getByName(newBankName);
            newBank.addEmployee(employee);
            employee.setBank(newBank);

        }
        if (!employee.getFunction().getName().equals(newFunctionName)) {
            employee.getFunction().removeEmployee(employee);
            employee.setFunction(null);
            Functions newFunction = functionService.getByName(newFunctionName);
            newFunction.addEmployee(employee);
            employee.setFunction(newFunction);

        }
    }   
}
```

> the exception stack trace Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry
>   'dkfhks32' for key 'REGISTRATIONNUMBER'   at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:115)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:960)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1116)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1066)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1396)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1051)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:127)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ProfiledConnectionWrapper40$1.invoke(ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.java:437)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy268.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:898)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change the `bank` for an `employee` by removing the reference of existing bank first. You can simply go:

```
if (!employee.getBank().getName().equals(newBankName)) {
    Bank newBank = bankService.getByName(newBankName);
    //You must also do an entity validation/null check here. The newBank might not be present after all.
    employee.setBank(newBank);       
}
```

This will update the mappings correctly. Same goes for updating `function` of an `employee`